# PhpStorm won't start - flashes logo then goes away

Tags: phpstorm

After restarting my PC and clicking the PhpStorm icon to launch it, the splash screen loads, then nothing does.  PhpStorm will not open.

Answer (score 0):

### Three Step Solution

1. From [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206376699-PHPStorm-Won-t-Start-?page=1#community_comment_115000054044) (copied below in case the URL ever dies):

> I had the same problem on the same day so perhaps it relates to a Windows update.  (Edit - ignore that, my problem happened on January 17th, 2017 not 2016).
>
> I renamed C:\Users\USERNAME.PhpStorm2016.3 to something else and it then started and allowed me to import my settings, which seems to have worked.  I hope this helps others as this is much easier than rebuilding my Windows profile.

NOTE: On older versions of PhpStorm the path is `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde100`

2. Upon restarting Windows after renaming my PhpStorm directory I tried to import the settings from my renamed `C:\Users\USERNAME\OLD.WebIde100\config` but got an error that `settings.jar` could not be found.
3. I closed PhpStorm and renamed my new `.WebIde100` to `NEW.WebIde100` and my `OLD.WebIde100` back to `.WebIde100`.  I did not have to restart my computer; launching PhpStorm again brought back my old settings.

---

I'm not sure why all this was needed, but it worked for me so I thought I'd share.